# Easiest way to create TeX macro/code to access symbols from particular font?

Tags: fonts, packages, fontspec, font-encodings, package-writing

I would like to use [CASIO fonts](https://edu.casio.com/education/fontset/dl/ClassWizFontSet.zip) here.
[image]

1 - I would like to create a way to use LaTeX to get these "icon"s. For example, use `\On` for the *ON* button, and ect. Assuming we have to do some more work here to find the `mapping` of those icons here...

2 - As you can see that target computers (final PDF verwiers) may not have the font installed. I know that we can embed font into PDF. Can this be done using latex too?

[image]

3 - I don't mind using a normal `.tex` to enable me to do so, or creating a `package`. But I have minimal experience in creating one, so `quick-and-easy` would be the best.

Comment: Have a look at fontspec. You can easily define a new font family with the fonts (assuming they are TTF/OTF). Then just use your font family as in `{\myfontfamily\char"...}` where `...` is the unicode code point of the symbol you want to use. And then you can create macros for every shorthand you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call the glyphs by number rather than “by character”. With the following code we can gather the number of each glyph in the font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newfontface{\casio}{CASIO ClassWiz}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  Path=./ClassWizSeriesFontSet/,
]

\begin{document}

{\casio\xdef\casiofont{\the\font}}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\count255=32

\loop\ifnum\count255<"10FFFF
\advance\count255 1
  \iffontchar\casiofont\count255 \the\count255\ {\casio\char\count255}\endgraf\fi
\repeat

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For your document you can look up the characters you need and define

```
\newfontface{\casio}{CASIO ClassWiz}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  Path=./ClassWizSeriesFontSet/,
]
```

(if you install the font system wide, you don't need those options, of course; otherwise, adjust the path).

Next, assign macros to the glyphs you need:

```
\newcommand{\casiosymbol}[1]{{\normalfont\casio\symbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\CLeft}{\casiosymbol{33}}
\newcommand{\CEquiv}{\casiosymbol{34}}
\newcommand{\CFactorial}{\casiosymbol{37}}
```

You can improve the list at any time.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's what I meant by "mapping the icons". I will explore more using this method.

Comment: Is there any advantage of doing it this way?

Comment: @AlanMunn I see no advantage in using characters.

Comment: @egreg The advantage for me was that I could simply use the character map provided with the font to assign names.

Answer (score 12):

It's really not hard to do, but it would make sense to make it a package.

### Update

I've now packaged this as a package with command names for all the keys. It is now on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/casiofont).  Since I don't use the calculator, suggestions are welcome for more appropriate names for some of the keys.  You can submit them at https://github.com/amunn/casiofont/.

### Sample document

Here's a sample document. Fonts are embedded by default so any viewer should be able to view the resultant file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{casiofont}
\begin{document}
{\casio \Shift\Alpha\UpArrow\DownArrow\LeftArrow\RightArrow}

\textcasio{\UpArrow}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I would wrap `\casio`inside the `\newcommand*` macros, within an extra set of braces. That way, you can write `\shift` instead of `\textcasio{\shift}` and not get `q`.

Comment: Additionally, you should probably load CASIO ClassWiz with `Scale=MatchUppercase`.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, that's a good idea. I'll update shortly.

Comment: Oh, and having the internal macros you define in your packages include an `@` makes it less likely that they’ll clash with user-defined commands.

Comment: @Davislor Of course. But this package has none. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn For some reason, I just saw this! Many thanks. FYI, `\UnknownA` is `Menu` in Chinese/Japanese and `\UnknownB` is `On`.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Thanks. I've updated the names an pushed a new version to CTAN.